# Error After Adding ios::app to C++ code - fstream

Tags: c++, macos, fstream

I'm not a very experience programmer (I'm just learning at school) and we've learned about how to use fstream. I had a few ideas with what I wanted to try with the new information, so I tried writing some code for a username and password. However, I want to make sure that when someone doesn't have their name in the text file, the program will add their name to the file. When I add ios::app to the .open() function, it gives me the error message "Cannot locate external files. The program will now exit.". I'll post the code below. By the way, I'm on a Mac computer, using Netbeans 7.3.1.

```
fstream names;
//creates variable
fstream passwords;
//creates variable
names.open("/Users/myName/desktop/names.txt");
//accesses file "names.txt"
passwords.open("/Users/myName/desktop/passwords.txt");
//accesses file "passwords.txt"
if (!passwords || !names) {
    cerr<<"Cannot locate external files. The program will now exit."<<endl;
    exit(1);
}
//gives error message if files could not be found
```

The code above does not give me the error message, but I will not be able to add to the files, either.

```
fstream names;
//creates variable
fstream passwords;
//creates variable
names.open("/Users/myName/desktop/names.txt", ios::app);
//accesses file "names.txt"
passwords.open("/Users/myName/desktop/passwords.txt", ios::app);
//accesses file "passwords.txt"
if (!passwords || !names) {
    cerr<<"Cannot locate external files. The program will now exit."<<endl;
    exit(1);
}
//gives error message if files could not be found
```

The code above gives me the error message.

Comment: I consider it good practice to individually check the files. Since you check both files you should make sure your condition is what you want it to be: Your program fails if it cannot open the passwords file and if it can open the names file. You probably mean to write `if (!passwords || !names)` or factor out the negation which would read `if (!(passwords && names))` according to Boolean logic.

Comment: Right, when I retyped the code, I forgot to add the "!" characters. I did add them in the original code, though. I meant to write that in the post.

Comment: Didn't you mean (!passwords || !names)?
Anyway, you should check if you have permissions to create a file in that directory.

Comment: I did mean (!passwords || !names), as I wrote it in the original code. However, that still does not solve the problem, unfortunately. If I take away "ios::app", the program works, but then I can't append the new person's name to the text file, as it will overwrite it.

Comment: Just to avoid future confusion, I'm going to edit the post so that the (!passwords || !names) part is correct.